# Streaming a zip file from node api to angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, zip

Using archiver to zip a file in node api and stream the zip to angular frontend.  The file downloads but doesn't open with No such file or directory when unzipping.  I feel like the zip is incomplete or not converted properly somehow.  Also, the console log message never gets fired in the finalize callback. Any suggestions?

Service file

```
function downloadDisclosuresZip(tid, files) {

        return $http.post('api/disclosures/download/' + tid, files, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/octet-stream',
                'responseType': 'arraybuffer'
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            var filename = "disclosures.zip";
            console.log(response);
            openSaveAsDialog(filename, response.data, 'application/zip');
        });

    }

    function openSaveAsDialog(filename, content, mediaType) {
        var blob = new Blob([content], {
            type: mediaType
        });
        saveAs(blob, filename);
    }
```

API (node)

```
.post(function (req, res) {
        var tid = req.params.tid;
        console.log(req.body);
        var files = req.body;

        console.log('tid:' + tid);
        console.log('files:' + JSON.stringify(files));

        var archive = archiver('zip', {
            zlib: {
                level: 9
            } // Sets the compression level.
        });

        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; disclosures.zip');


        archive.on('warning', function (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                // log warning
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // throw error
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }
        });

        archive.on('end', function (err) {
            console.log("achive ended");

        });

        archive.on('finish', function (err) {
            console.log("achive finished");

        });

        archive.on('close', function (err) {
            console.log("achive closed");

        });

        // good practice to catch this error explicitly
        archive.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });

        archive.pipe(res);

        archive.append('string cheese!', {
            name: 'file2.txt'
        });


        archive.finalize(function (err, bytes) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }

            console.log('Disclosures Zip Created: ', bytes);
        });
});
```

Comment: have you tried just saving the archive on the node side as well, would help to narrow down if it is a server side issue or something between the client/server.


  `var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/example.zip');`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver

Comment: if i set var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/example.zip'); and pipe the archive there it works as expected.  I guess piping to the response is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this via using this

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
req.on('data',(data)=>{
     writeStream.write(data, 'binary' );
})
```

writing a file with correct encoding.